How to limit depth of `git diff --dirstat`
I have a git branch and I'd like to show how much of its changes are due to tests vs. implementation. I can run:
git diff master..my-branch --dirstat

and I get something like:
  22.2% app/foo/abc/
   9.4% app/bar/abc/
  14.0% test/foo/abc/
  42.2% test/bar/abc/
  10.6% test/baz/qux/

Is there a way I can limit the depth to which this summary goes, so it will instead show the following?
  33.1% app/
  66.8% test/


According to man git diff, the dirstat command has the option of setting a lower percentage limit so that directories that contribute less than that limit aren't shown. See the diff.dirstat entry (specifically, the limit section) under CONFIGURATION in man git diff.
